# how many parameters can I

Tags: arrays, shell, parameters

I have this problem: while running

```
./choose_words.sh $NWORDS_s1 $NWORDS_s2 $NWORDS_s3 $NWORDS_s4
```

In choose_words, after doing `nwords=($1 $2 $3 $4)`, `$4` seems not to contain any value. So, if try to print:

```
echo ${nwords[4]} # I get nothing from this
```

while if I try to print `echo ${nwords[*]}`, the array `nwords` has actually the forth element with its real value.

Does this make any sense to you?

Comment: In what shell?  In general, the shell does not support arrays, so you must be talking about a specific shell.

Comment: Make sure you quote the parameters you pass to the script to protect those with whitespace. Similarly when you create the array: `nwords=("$1" "$2" "$3" "$4")`  or more simply `nwords=("$@")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array indexing starts from `0`, so you need to use `${nwords[3]}` to get the fourth element of the array.

Answer (score 3):

Array indices start at 0, not 1 ;)

i.e.:

```
echo ${nwords[0]} # This is the 1st element, corresponding to $1
echo ${nwords[1]} # This is the 2nd element, corresponding to $2
echo ${nwords[2]} # This is the 3rd element, corresponding to $3
echo ${nwords[3]} # This is the 4th element, corresponding to $4
```